# list_comments Ruby implementation with YouTube video_id

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

Having trouble implementing the list_comments method in the following code example (n.b. the API is initialised successfully):

```
# initialize API
service = Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::YouTubeService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

response = service.list_comments('snippet, replies')
```

Currently the method returns the following error:

> missingRequiredParameter: No filter selected. Expected one of: `id`, `idParam`, `parentId` (`Google::Apis::ClientError`)

I have successfully tested the API call here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list

What I'm struggling with is when I test the API call I can pass a `videoId` to identify a resource, however the method implementation does not allow for this. Could anyone shed some light on how to pass a `videoId` to the method call?

Comment: Take a look at the "view source" in the docs [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google%2FApis%2FYoutubeV3%2FYouTubeService:list_comments). I wonder if it would work to patch this to accept the `videoId` param. You could add another line in there: `command.query['videoId'] = videoId unless videoId.nil?` No guarantee this will work, just a hunch

Comment: Thanks for your reply Max! I've seen the library you pointed me to, but that's the method's actual implementation by the API..

Comment: Yes, im saying you could patch that method

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! The method that allows you to specify video_id (or channel_id) to select a specific resource is: list_comment_threads from the Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::YouTubeService module.

```
response = service.list_comment_threads('snippet', video_id: 'hy1v891n3kA').to_json
```